# How to close resources shared between junits?

Tags: java, junit

I have many junit 4 test classes with many tests.
Many of these tests need a DataSource to access a database.

To speed up tests, I would like to share a single DataSource for all test classes.
That would avoid connection cost.

So I have put the DataSource in a static variable.

But I have not found a way to close it!

With @Rule + TestWatcher, we can execute code before and after a single test...
With @ClassRule + TestWatcher, we can execute code before and after a single test class...

But how to execute code after the execution of all executed test classes ?

The test suite doesn't seems appropriate, because I am executing either all, one, or any subset of the junits tests.

Any idea?

Comment: Without @AfterClass or testSuites, the only thing coming into my mind is to implement your own custom TestRunner, not sure if it´s worth though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [JVM shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) does not appear too ugly in that case.

Far more reliable than a finalize() method called only if the object is garbage collected.

Not called if process interrupted, but in that case there nothing can be done anyway. So I did not find major drawbacks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClassRule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/ClassRule.html)

```
public static class GlobalDataSource extends ExternalResource
  private int count = 0;
  private DataSource dataSource;

  private GlobalDataSource() {};

  public static final GlobalDataSource INSTANCE = new GlobalDataSource();

  public DataSource get() {
    if (dataSource == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Override
  protected void before() throws Throwable {
    if (count++ == 0) {
      dataSource = createDataSource();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void after() {
    if (--count == 0) {
      try {
        destroyDataSource(dataSource);
      } finally {
        dataSource = null;
      }
    }
  };
};
```

In your tests:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class FooTest {
  @ClassRule public static GlobalDataSource source = GlobalDataSource.INSTANCE;

  @Test
  public void readDataSource() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then create a suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(FooTest.class, BarTest.class ...)
public class AllTests {
  @ClassRule public static GlobalDataSource source = GlobalDataSource.INSTANCE;
}
```

Be aware that global state in tests can be just as problematic as global state in code. A failure in one test could lead other tests to fail.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting and inventive solution which works when executing either a test class or the suite. Unfortunately, it does not work while executing a set of test classes, from a package for example. I am still investigating for another solution, but it seems hopeless.

Comment: Use http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp to create a suite that runs all of the tests in a package